# How to get location through Dioxus?

Tags: wasm-bindgen, dioxus

It seems that you can get GPS location through the browser APIs using `wasm-bindgen` but I just can't find an example for it.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dioxus-std](https://github.com/DioxusLabs/dioxus-std) to get the current location of the user using GPS. [Here is an example](https://github.com/DioxusLabs/dioxus-std/blob/master/examples/geolocation/src/main.rs).